# Elements of array have incomplete type

Tags: c, arrays

So basically i'm supposed to make a program that acts as a password manager for 5 different "websites". When I declare the functions and main method all in one file it runs perfectly. However when I use a header file I get the error shown

functions.h

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H_  
#define FUNCTIONS_H_

struct entry;

void requestEntry(struct entry *data);
void displaySummary(struct entry *data);
void displayEntry(struct entry *data);

#endif
```

functions.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "functions.h"

struct entry{
    char webName[32];
    char userName[32];
    char password[32];
};

void requestEntry(struct entry *data){
    printf("Please enter the following items: \n");
    printf("Website name: ");
    scanf("%s", data->webName);
    printf("Username: ");
    scanf("%s", data->userName);
    printf("Password: ");
    scanf("%s", data->password);
}

void displaySummary(struct entry *data){
    printf(" - %s\n", data->webName);
}

void displayEntry(struct entry *data){
    printf("Website: %s\n", data->webName);
    printf("Username: %s\n", data->userName);
    printf("Password: %s\n", data->password);

}
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "functions.h"

int main()
{
struct entry sites[5];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    requestEntry(&sites[i]);
}

printf("\n");
printf("Summary: \n");

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    printf("%d", (i + 1));
    displaySummary(&sites[i]);
}

bool cont = true;
int i;

while (cont){
    printf("Type in a number from 1 to 5 to pull up the entry, or type 0 to exit: ");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    if (i == 0){
        cont = false;
        continue;
    }
    printf("\n");
    displayEntry(&sites[i - 1]);
}
}
```

ERROR: elements of array 'entry sites [5]' have incomplete type

I tried building the program in a different IDE and it said that my array size was too large, when its obviously only 5 structs. I know that the code I have does work because like I said it runs perfectly when everything is in one file.

Comment: Ask yourself how `main()` has any knowledge what a `struct entry` *looks like*. Its *definition* is buried in another .c file. Kinda need to know if you're going to do this: `struct entry sites[5];`

Comment: try move definition of "struct entry" to .c file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with such separation is that the inner structure of your `struct entry` becomes private to the `functions.c` translation unit. This may or may not be desirable.

- If you wish to keep the `struct` private, switch to dynamic allocation
- If you do not mind exposing your `struct`, move its definition to the header file.

Here is the first approach: add a function to the header

```
struct entry *allocateEntries(size_t count);
```

Define this function in your `functions.c` file by calling `malloc(sizeof(struct entry)*count)`. Now you can replace

```
struct entry sites[5];
```

with

```
struct entry *sites = allocateEntries(5);
```

Don't forget to add `free(sites)` to the end of `main()`.

Comment: I moved the definition of my struct to my header file, however now im getting errors stating "undefined reference to `requestEntry(entry*)" and that shows up for all my functions

Comment: @HunterTipton That's strange. You didn't by accident move the `#include` line along with the five lines of `struct` definition with it, did you?

Comment: No i did not, I only moved the structure definition

Comment: @HunterTipton I just tried this - replaced the `struct` declaration with the definition, and removed the definition from the .c file. The code compiled without any issues.

Comment: Actually something strange happened, it seems that when I run the code on one IDE (Code::Blocks) it gives me the error I mentioned. However when I ran it on another IDE (Microsoft Visual Studio 2013) it worked flawlessly, that is after moving the struct definition

Comment: @HunterTipton I ran the compile from the command line, and it completed without errors or warnings, too.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight "undefined reference to..." sounds like `functions..c` generated object code (windows, so probably `functions.obj`) is  missing from the link-step in the CodeBlocks IDE. (uptick, btw)

Answer (score 1):

You can't declare an array of `struct entry` somewhere where the definition of `struct entry` isn't visible; the compiler doesn't know how big to make each element of the array.

The straightforward thing, in your case, is to move the definition of `struct entry` from functions.c to functions.h.